# Segmentation fault on main

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have small C program. When I compile it with `gcc`, everything works fine, but when I try to run it I get this message:

> ```
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ```

I tried to debug it with `gdb and`when I place a breakpoint on `main()` and start the program, I get this message in `gdb`:

> Single stepping until exit from function main, which has no line
>   number information.
>
> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>
> 0x00007ffff7a56ad4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

And this is the very beginning of mine mani() function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

   long N;
   double *A, *B, *C, t;

   srand(time(NULL));

   N = atoi(argv[1]);
   A = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   B = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   C = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
   matFillSimple(N, A, 1.0);
   matFillSimple(N, B, 2.0);
   matFillSimple(N, C, 0.0);
...
```

Comment: could we have the code of matFillSimple ?

Comment: What is the value of `N`?

Comment: You don't check whether you got an `argv[1]` before you start using it.  That could cause you to crash.  You don't check whether N is plausible before you start using it.  That could cause you to crash too.

Comment: Also, `atoi()` returns an `int` and `N` is a `long`.

Comment: Can you try compiling with `-g` and trying to step through again? That should give you line numbers, so you'll be able to see which line causes the segfault.

Comment: @AlexReynolds: `atoi()` returning an `int` is good; it means that you're less likely to overflow the maximum size of an array.  It is also perfectly valid; the compiler will convert.

Comment: @pierre-emmanuel-lallemant: matFillSimple() is just a simple matrix fill, like: for(i = 0; i < N; i ++)
      for(j = 0; j < N; j ++)
         mat[i * N + j] = val;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that the type of `N` matches the return value of `atoi()`. Avoid relying on implicit type conversions as this can lead to problems where a value gets turned into something you weren't expecting.

If you compile with all warnings (`gcc -Wall`) then you should probably see a warning to this effect. There are other warnings you can turn on with GCC, [listed in the documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). Compiling with warnings a good habit to get into.

Further, get into the (good) habit of error checking when handling pointers. Be sure to check if you allocate memory successfully after each call.

In other words:

```
A = (double *) malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
...
```

should be something like:

```
double *A = NULL;
A = malloc(N * N * sizeof(double));
if (!A) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not allocate space for A\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
...
```

Repeat for each of your `double` pointers.

My suspicion is that your value of `N` is so large (and `N * N` even larger) that your system runs out of memory before you can run `matFillSimple()`. This should help troubleshoot that possibility.

Comment: And don't cast the return value from malloc in C, it _will_ bite you at some point :-)

Comment: `atoi()` returns an `int`. Converting the result to `long` doesn't cause any problems (though it likely implies either than `N` should have been defined as an `int`, or that you should be using `atol()` rather than `atoi()`).